# iOS Use Array in Multiple ViewControllers

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I have a NSMutableArray that I create in ViewControllerA, and I fill that array with default data in an instance method (in the same .m file).  The array values then become section titles in my tableView.

I have ViewControllerB in which I have a Picker and then a Textfield.  I'm trying to load the Picker with the array from ViewControllerA so that they can choose a section and then via text field add a new item to that section.

What is the best way to pull the array data from ViewControllerA and send it to the picker in ViewControllerB, so that when a Pick + Textfield entry is submitted, I can update the ViewControllerA table with a New Item in the Section that matches what they Picked?  Right now, the original array seems to be contained in an instance of ViewControllerA, so I'm assuming I have to make this array more publicly accessible.

tl;dr How do I set the datasource of a Picker to be an array that's located in a different ViewController?

I've been Google/Stacking and haven't been able to find any fundamental answers that relate the the most recent version of Xcode (5.0.2 now).  Thank you!

Comment: Does the viewControllerB being pushed by ViewControllerA?

Comment: This is an extremely basic question asked and answered many other places. It does not illustrate minimum understanding of the subject.

Comment: assign the array to destination viewControllerB object when pushing viewControllerB. use delegate to update the viewcontrollerA array when new item is added in ViewControllerB

Answer (score 1):

If you use same array in multiple view controller use NSUserDefaults

`NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"pickerArray"];`

Answer (score 0):

Lets say this is your viewcontrollerA and it contains mutableArray arrayControllerA and also contains some value. So for passing array value to viewcontrollerB. You need to first declare mutable array property in viewcontrollerB

In viewcontrollerB.h file

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray 
  *arrayControllerB;
```

Now In viewcontrollerA.m file

```
UIViewController *secondViewController= 
[[[UIViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"viewControllerBNibName"] 
  bundle:nil];
   [secondViewController.arrayControllerB=
  self.arrayControllerA
 [self.navigationController 
 pushViewController:myNewViewController 
 animated:YES];
```

Comment: That won't even compile. You need to use the correct class name, also you have an extra pair of square bracket on the constructor, and a random square b in front of the instance variable assignment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to approach this. The correct answer really depends on what the structure of your app is, and in particular how the two different vcs get instantiated.

If viewControllerA (the main list) is the main vc of the app and viewControllerB (the picker) is triggered by an action somewhere on it, then the approach that Hussain suggests should work- you just need to create an instance variable on viewControllerB and set it with the original array on vcA.

If the structure of the app is more complex you could keep the section data in an instance variable on some other object (perhaps a higher level view controller or the app delegate) and then pass it to vcA or vcB whenever one of the other is instantiated.

If you use the appDelegate you could take advantage of its singleton accessor (`[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]`) although this would probably not be considered good OO style - the former approach is better because it's easier to understand the flow of the app.